# using unbound with dnscrypt-proxy

Tags: networking, dns, proxy

My operating system is Ubuntu14.04 , I'm trying to use dnscrypt-proxy along with unbound,using unbound listening to port 53, forwarding name-resolve  request to port 40, which is being listened by dnscrypt-proxy.

I set things up, it works well but after the computer is rebooted ,since the dnscrypt-proxy cannot be installed as a daemon, I have to run it manually(unbound is by default installed as running when booted). At this moment, the domain name can't be resolved at all. Using `nslookup` to test name resolving on port 53, coming out with an "serv fail" message, but on the 40 port, name resolved successfully. Using `lsof: -i` command shows that the unbound is listening to  `localhost:domain` port, dnscrypt is listening to localhost:40. Everything just seems to be set well, but it just doesn't work.

However at this moment if I terminate the unbound process, and start it manually, the domain names can be resolved correctly on port 53. Check the port these programs is listening to, it is still those two ports, nothing changed. But it just works.It seems to be the pipe line between two programs need to be "refreshed" or something.

why this happen ? How can I configure it to run dnscrypt before unbound , or other ways to ease myself from typing those commands repeatedly?

Comment: i have write some tutorial about it on http://ixycharme.blogspot.com/2015/09/using-unbound-and-dnscrypt-proxy-in.html?view=sidebar
i hope it helping

Answer (score 0):

You said you have to start `dnscypt-proxy` manually. May be you should use dnscrypt-proxy packages from my PPA :

https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt

As dnscrypt-proxy starts automatically.

I have tested it with unbound on a previous version of dnscrypt-proxy. Still I need to reinstall the unbound configuration for the latest version of dnscrypt-proxy. At that time I may be able to give you advices.

I just posted yesterday a test version of dnscrypt-proxy woking with systemd for Vivid 15.04.